# Using Linq to sql for windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, linq-to-sql, nfc, local-database

I am trying to show out History for my windows 8 application which includes date, time , Floor ,Zone , Longitutde and latitude. I tried the code below but there was no output in it above.

THe image you can see on the link down below that I want to show on my application.But I can see nothing when I run my program.

I have three classes for using linq to sql to retrieve database and show information through it.The main class is History.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;   
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Linq;


namespace SmartParking
{

public partial class History : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private readonly HistoryDataContext historylog; 
    public History()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       // createDB();





    }

    public HistoryDataContext Log
    {
        get { return historylog; }
    }

    public void createDB()
    {
        using (HistoryDataContext historylog = new HistoryDataContext(HistoryDataContext.DBConnectionString))
        {
            if (historylog.DatabaseExists() == false)
            {
                historylog.CreateDatabase();
                addDataDB();
            }
        }

    }

    public void addDataDB()
    {
        using (HistoryDataContext historylog = new HistoryDataContext(HistoryDataContext.DBConnectionString))
        {
            HistoryDB hdb = new HistoryDB
            {
               // Date = DateTime.Today,
               // Time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay,
                Zone = Checkin.Zone_st,
                Floor = Checkin.Floor_st,
                location_latitude = Checkin.Latitud_do,
                location_longtitud = Checkin.Longtitude_do
            };
            historylog.history.InsertOnSubmit(hdb);
            historylog.SubmitChanges();
            GetHistoryLog();

        }
    }
    public IList<HistoryDB> GetHistoryLog()
    {
        IList<HistoryDB> HistoryList = null;
        using (HistoryDataContext historylog = new HistoryDataContext(HistoryDataContext.DBConnectionString))
        {
            IQueryable<HistoryDB> query = from histoy in historylog.history select histoy;
            HistoryList = query.ToList();
        }
        return HistoryList ;
    }


}
}
```

The next class is HistoryDB.cs with  the tables and columns

```
[Table]
    public class HistoryDB 
{

    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public DateTime Date
    { get; set; }

    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public TimeSpan Time
    { get; set; }

    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public String Zone
    { get; set; }

    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public String Floor
    { get; set; }

    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public double location_latitude
    { get; set; }

    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public double location_longtitud
    { get; set; }

}
```

The next class is HistoryDataContext.cs.

```
public class HistoryDataContext:DataContext 
{
    public static string DBConnectionString = "Data Source=isostore:/History.sdf";
    public HistoryDataContext(string DBConnectionString)
        : base(DBConnectionString)
    {
}

   public Table<HistoryDB> history
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<HistoryDB>();
        }
    }


}
```

What I am trying is to get information from the NFC tag and store it in the local database and then retrieve it in the history page. The code below is to read from nfc tag but I dunno how again to save in the local databse from there and retrive it back in the history page.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Networking.Proximity;
using NdefLibrary.Ndef;
using NdefLibraryWp.Ndef;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets; // needed for DataReader, DataWriter
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;
using System.Text;
using Windows.Phone.PersonalInformation;
using SmartParking.Resources;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace SmartParking
{

public partial class Checkin : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private ProximityDevice _device;
    private long _subscriptionIdNdef;

    public static double Latitud_do { get; set; }
    public static double Longtitude_do { get; set; }
    public static string Floor_st { get; set; }
    public static string Zone_st { get; set; }

    History store = new History();


    public Checkin()
    {
        InitializeProximityDevice();
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void SetLogStatus(string newStatus)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { if (LogStatus != null) LogStatus.Text = newStatus; });
    }

    private void SetFloorStatus(string newStatus)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { if (FloorStatus != null) FloorStatus.Text = newStatus; });
    }



    private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" ");
    }


    private void InitializeProximityDevice()
    {
        _device = Windows.Networking.Proximity.ProximityDevice.GetDefault();
        if (_device != null)
        {
            _subscriptionIdNdef = _device.SubscribeForMessage("NDEF", MessageReceivedHandler);

        }

    }


    private void MessageReceivedHandler(ProximityDevice sender, ProximityMessage message)
    {
        var rawMsg = message.Data.ToArray();
        var ndefMessage = NdefMessage.FromByteArray(rawMsg);


        ////// Loop over all records contained in the NDEF message
        foreach (NdefRecord record in ndefMessage)
        {

            if (NdefTextRecord.IsRecordType(record))
            {
                // Convert and extract URI info
                var textRecord = new NdefTextRecord(record);
                //var str = textRecord.Text;
                string[] str = textRecord.Text.Split('|');

                var latitude = str[2];
                Latitud_do = double.Parse(latitude);
                var longtitude = str[3];
                Longtitude_do = double.Parse(longtitude);
                var Floor_st = str[0];
                var Zone_st = str[1];


                SetLogStatus("Floor: " + Floor_st + " Zone: " + Zone_st );
                SetFloorStatus("Longitude: " + latitude + "   Longitude: " + longtitude);
                store.addDataDB();

            }
        }
      }
 }
```

}

The Image of the table is in the link below

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g87yta6hegjstge/Untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: Have you got your view to add to your question? In the view have you created the bindings to the table?

Comment: No I dont know anything about the view and how to create bindings to the table .Sorry for being so foolish but I am just a beginner.Can you help me in it or atleast providing me with links so I could understand about the view and binding related to my code

Comment: Do you really intend to run a SQL Server on a phone?

Comment: The data I have to save is not much so I thought to use Linq to sql and a local database

Comment: It's fine using SQL Server Compact (.sdf) on Windows Phone, although I've only used SQLite as I use that on iOS and Android too. If it's simple data or not that much, you can also just create classes and store your populated objects in IsolatedStorage. I've found this works well. As AB has answered your question I take you don't need the views explanation?

Comment: Actually I need the views explaination cause maybe thats where my application is lacking behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

In Database There Should be a **Primary key** otherwise it would Throw an Exception and the Datatype that is **TimeSpan** not supported so you need to take **DateTime** or **String** as Done Below :

```
[Table]
    public class HistoryDB
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
        public DateTime Date
        { get; set; }

        [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
        public DateTime Time
        { get; set; }

        [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
        public String Zone
        { get; set; }

        [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
        public String Floor
        { get; set; }

        [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
        public double location_latitude
        { get; set; }

        [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
        public double location_longtitud
        { get; set; }

    }

        public void addDataDB()
        {
            using (HistoryDataContext historylog = new HistoryDataContext(HistoryDataContext.DBConnectionString))
            {
                HistoryDB hdb = new HistoryDB
                {
                    Id = 0,
                     Date = DateTime.Today,
                    Time = DateTime.Now,
                    Zone = "Zone",
                    Floor = "Floore",
                    location_latitude = 00.00,
                    location_longtitud = 00.00
                };
                historylog.history.InsertOnSubmit(hdb);
                historylog.SubmitChanges();
                GetHistoryLog();

            }
        }
```

I have implemented above thing and its working Properly

Comment: Thank you for your help but its still not working ,its showing nothing on the history page . What I am trying is to get information from the NFC tag and store it in the local database and then retrieve it in the history page.

Comment: it would be databinding error. I have tried with the above data and its working good. so if this answer helped you, accept it for future reference for others. I think you should edit in Question and add it to Question not in answer. I would be Negative marking for it. Be careful and please dont increase your Queries one by one, let it be clear in one Question

Comment: Can you suggest me how to get over this binding error?

Comment: first of all check whether you are getting data or not from function you are trying then if data is valid and its getting from function, check your binding properties are binded properly or not. This can be a good step to check

Comment: the data is valid but about the binding , Does the data from the database shows itself by the list property or I have to add something in the History.xaml to show as rows and columns

Comment: you can refer this answer for data binding. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243875/wp8-longlistselector-item-add-controls/24244423#24244423. 
Why have you rejected answer ? can i know Reason for Accepting and then Rejecting answer ?

Comment: I am able to show the data as AB told it works thanks! but I cant show the data that I read from the nfc tag in checkin class .Can Anybody help me in that please?